# Maze solving algorithm gets stuck between two places

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I'm trying to make a program (in Java) that solves a maze as part of a school project.  I'm almost done, but my algorithm seems to have a problem.  I'm using the right hand rule, but because of the way my maze is made, there isn't always a wall (see picture here? --not exactly mine, but very similar http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Prim_Maze.svg).  Consequently, The algorithm just bounces back and forth between the same two places.  Any tips/hints/help on how to avoid this problem would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!  Here's the code I'm working with right now:

```
public void solve(){
    /*if you can go right go right 
    else if you can go forward go forward 
    else if you can go left go left 
    else if you can go back go back */

    int direction = 0; //0=down, 1=right, 2=up, 3=left

    int lastXSquare = 0;
    int lastYSquare = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        tryDirection(direction);
        hasMoved = false;
        direction = 0;
        if(lastXSquare == xSquareLocation && lastYSquare == ySquareLocation){
            tryDirection(++direction);
            hasMoved = false;
            direction = 0;
        }

    }
    if(solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation]){
        lastXSquare = xSquareLocation;
        lastYSquare = ySquareLocation;
        direction++;
    }
    //if we get stuck between two, change the starting direction to try and break out of the loop 
    // *****NOT WORKIKNG***
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        tryDirection(direction);
        hasMoved = false;
        direction = 0;
        if(lastXSquare == xSquareLocation && lastYSquare == ySquareLocation){
            tryDirection(++direction);
            hasMoved = false;
            direction = 0;
        }

    }


}

private void tryDirection(int direction){

    if(direction == 0){
        moveVertically(1);
        if(hasMoved){
            if(solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation]){
                moveVertically(-1);
                direction++;
            }
            else
                solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation] = true;
        }
        else{
            direction++;
        }
    }
    if(direction == 1){
        moveHorizontally(1);
        if(hasMoved){
            if(isSolved()){   return;   }
            if(solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation]){
                moveHorizontally(-1);
                direction++;
            }
            else
                solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation] = true;
        }
        else{
            direction++;
        }
    }
    if(direction == 2){
        moveVertically(-1);
        if(hasMoved){
            if(solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation]){
                moveVertically(1);
                direction++;
            }
            else
                solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation] = true;
        }
        else{
            direction++;
        }
    }
    if(direction == 3){
        moveHorizontally(-1);
        if(hasMoved){
            if(solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation]){
                moveHorizontally(1);
                direction++;
            }
            else
                solution[xSquareLocation][ySquareLocation] = true;
        }
        else{
            direction = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is the maze itself represented?

Comment: You don't seem to be implementing the right hand rule here... Which direction is right depends on which direction you are facing in the RHR algorithm.

Comment: @Alcanzar otherwhise it would be called 'east way rule' :-)

Comment: @liangricha The maze itself is just the lines.  I can get the start and end point of each line/wall, but that's it.

Comment: @Alcanzar I think I see what you mean, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Do you have any suggestions as to I could go about that?

Comment: It comes back to how is the maze represented?  If you've only got the moveHorizontally/moveVertically methods you can call and have to check the flag after, your solution will be dramatically different than if you can write a "isOpenToRight()" method that inspects maze walls.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like **you are doing some variation of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)** - you are exploring a 'branch' (a single path) on the maze, and hope to find a solution.

However, **DFS is not complete.** It does not guarantee to find a path if one exists, and might get stuck in infinite loops. This is exacrtly the behavior you are observing.

In addition - it is not *optimal* - even the path it found, is not guaranteed to be the best (shortest) one.

An optimal and complete algorithm that solves this problem is [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

In BFS you explore all possible moves up to depth 1. Then up to depth 2, and so on and so on.

There are more advanced algorithms such as [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) (possibly with the [manhattan distance heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)), and [bi-directional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search), but you should stick to the simpler BFS for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not really following the right-hand rule. The rule should be interpreted local to your orientation, whereas you seem to be interpreting it relative to a global orientation.

What you should be doing is:

```
If I can move left - turn left and step forwards 
else If I can move forwards - step forwards 
else If I can move right - turn right and step forwards 
else turn right
```

where left, forwards, and right are relative to your current **orientation**.

The algorithm can be simplified to:

```
repeat
  If I could move left then 
    turn left
  else 
    if I can move forwards then 
      move forwards
    else 
      turn right
until exit reached
```

This should find the exit of any 2D maze where the entrance and exit are both on the external walls.